# Exact sequence $0\to I\cap J \to R \to (R/ I) \times (R/ J) \to R/ (I+J) \to 0$ and Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to find an exact sequence such that where $I$, $J$ are ideals of $R$. I know that I have to find  homomorphisms

\begin{align*}
&a\colon I\cap J \to R 
\\
&b\colon R \to (R/I) \times (R/J) 
\\
&c\colon(R/I) \times (R/J) \to R/(I+J)
\end{align*}

such that $\ker a=(0), \ker b=\operatorname{im}a, \operatorname{im}b=\ker c,\operatorname{im}c= R/(I+J)$ but I fail to. This is my first touch with this kind of sequences and I do not know how to think. Can someone help? Then I need to prove that this chain is a result of  the Chinese remainder theorem.

Edit: my tries so far for the functions (I do not think it is correct)
\begin{align*}
a(k)&=rk , r\in R \\
b(x)&=(\frac{1}{k} x-r , \frac{1}{k} x-r), \frac{1}{k}\in I\cap J \\
c(x,y)&=x+y+2r-\frac{x}{k}-\frac{y}{k}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Your guesses for $a$, $b$, and $c$ are not just incorrect - they don't even make sense. What does $a(k) = rk, r\in R$ mean? $a$ is supposed to take as input an element $k\in I\cap J$ and return as output an element of $R$. But $rk,r\in R$ looks like a family of elements of $R$. Did you mean to fix a particular element $r\in R$? Which one? Why not just use $r = 1$? For $b$ and $c$, why are you writing fractions? Finally, if you want an explanation of what this chain has to do with the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it would help to know what your statement of the Chinese Remainder Theorem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definitions are, well, weird. Your $a$ contains an unnecessary factor from $R$ which can be simply put as $r=1$. And once you have introduced this unneeded factor there you have to carry it around and take care of it while defining $b$ and $c$ which only complicates the matter.

On a final note: This appears as P. Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter $0$" exercise **V**$\mathbf{.6.1}$. I am not sure if you are aware of this but it might be good to know for future readers.

---

There are rather natural choices for $a$ and $b$ given by $I\cap J\to R$ being the inclusion and $R\to R/I\times R/J$ being componentwise reduction (i.e. $r\mapsto (r+I,r+J)$).
You can check quite easily that the $a$ is injective (which is equivalent to $\ker a=(0)$) and that $\ker b=I\cap J$ as $(r+I,r+J)=(I,J)$ iff $r\in I$ and $r\in J$ iff $r\in I\cap J$. The tricky part is $c$. One possible definition is

$$
c\colon R/I\times R/J\to R/(I+J),\,(r+I,s+J)\mapsto r-s+(I+J)\,.
$$

It is easy to check that this map is well-defined. Clearly $\operatorname{im}b\subseteq\ker c$. For the reverse inclusion take $(r+I,s+J)\in\ker c$. Then, $r-s\in I+J$, that is, there are $i\in I,j\in J$ such that $r-s=i+j$ iff $r-i=s+j$. It follows that

$$
b(r-i)=(r-i+I,s+j+J)=(r+I,s+J)
$$

which concludes the proof. The surjectivity of $c$, i.e. $\operatorname{im}c=R/(I+J)$, is straigtforward to check.

Regarding your second question: It is the other way around! That is, the Chinese Remainder Theorem is a direct consequences of this exact sequences. Indeed, the only assumption missing is comaximality of $I$ and $J$ which means $I+J=R$. In this case $R/(I+J)=0$ and exactness dictates $R/(I\cap J)\cong R/I\times R/J$.

---

Just for reference - for future readers and myself - I will include a more advanced proof of this proposition. First, note that
$$
0\to R\xrightarrow{x\mapsto(x,x)}R^2\xrightarrow{(x,y)\mapsto x-y} R\to 0
$$
is exact and likewise is the variation
$$
0\to I\cap J\to I\oplus J\to I+J\to 0
$$
as also mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363720/short-exact-sequences-every-mathematician-should-know). Now consider the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 @.
\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV
\\
0 @>>> I\cap J @>>> I\oplus J @>>> I+J @>>>0
\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV
\\
0 @>>> R @>>> R^2 @>>> R @>>>0
\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV
\\
0 @>>> R/I\cap J @>>> R/I\oplus R/J @>>> R/I+J @>>>0
\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @.
\\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 
\end{CD}

All columns are trivially exact (being quotient sequences) and the first two rows are exact too as indicated above. Moreover, the upper two rows are compatible being variations of diagonal embeddings and difference projections. If we now induce the last row similarily we are in the situation of the [$3\times3$ lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/3x3+lemma) (one of the basic diagram lemmata) and may conclude that
$$
0\to R/I\cap J\to R/I\oplus R/J\to R/I+J\to 0
$$
is exact. From hereon it is easy to recover the original statement.

Comment: Your reference for further readers payed off. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Define:
\begin{align*}
a(k) &= k &\text{ for }k\in I\cap J.\\ 
b(r) &= (r+I,r+J) &\text{ for }r\in R.\\
c(r+I,s+J) &= (r-s)+(I+J) &\text{ for }(r+I,s+J)\in R/I\times R/J.
\end{align*}

$a$ and $b$ are the "obvious" maps $I\cap J\to R$ and $R\to (R/I)\times (R/J)$. There is also an "obvious" map $(R/I)\times (R/J)$ given by $(r+I,s+J) \mapsto (r+s)+(I+J)$. But for exactness, we need to have $0 = c(b(r)) = c(r+I,r+J)$ for all $r\in R$, and this motivates using subtraction instead of addition in the definition of $c$ above.

I'll leave it to you to check that these are homomorphisms (this includes checking that $c$ is well-defined) and that the resulting sequence is exact.

Comment: can you simply define a function where ''you add an ideal'' to an element? Can you please tell me a good website or help me locate the right chapter on Altman Kleiman's A term of Commutative Algebra so I can study more about the maps topic?

Comment: @Vasilis If you've an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ you can consider for every element $r\in R$ its *equivalence class* (the equivalence relation being $r\sim s\iff r-s\in I$) in $R/I$ which we write as $r+I$. That you can simply define functions on equivalence class is a consequence of the [homomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms) (or $1.$ isomorphism theorem) which takes care of the important well-definedness.

Comment: @mrtaurho Thank you! I guess this answers my other comment! Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @Vasilis Glad to help! Consider [accepting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one of the given answers if you have no further questions.