# Solution verification of this question related to noetheranity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, noetherian

This question was asked in my quiz of commutative algebra and I attempted this question. I want to ask here whether my solution is correct or not. (What are the mistakes in the attempt).

> Question:   Let $I,J$ be ideals in a ring $A$ such that $I \cap J=\{0\}$. Show that $A$ is noetherian iff $A/I$ and $A/J$ are noetherian.

Attempt: Let $A$ be a noetherian ring $\implies$ Any $A$-module $M$ and any ascending chain of submodules stabilizes or every submodule is finitely generated.

Let $a\in A/I$ and $a'\in A/I$  . $ a-a' \in A/I$. $a= a_x +I $ and $a'=a_y +I$ such that $a_x , a_y \in A$  . $a-a' = a_x - a_y +I  \in A+I$.

$a(a_x +I) = a a_x +I \in A+I$ as $I$ is an ideal. So any $A/I$  submodule of $A/I$ is also a submodule of $A$-module.

So, $A/I$ will be noetherian and similarly, $A/J$ will be noetherian.

Conversly, let $I\cap J= \{0\}$ and $A/I$ and $A/J$ are notherian.

$A /I$ is finitely generated implies that there exists $a_1,..., a_n  $  all in $A$ such that  any $a_x \in A/I$ can be written as  $ a_x= a'_1 a_1 +... + a'_n a_n$.

Similarly there exists $a^*_1 ,..., a^*_m $ and  $a^"_1 ,..., a^"_m \in A$ such that any $a_y \in A/J$ can be written as $a_y = a^"_1 a^*_1 +...+ a^"_m a^*_m$ . To show that $A$ is finitely generated.

Any element $a_x = a_i +I $ such that $a_i \in A$ and $a_y = a_j + J$ such that $a_j \in A$.

Now let $a_i $ and $a_j$ in $A$ be arbitrary. Then $a_i +I = a'_1 a_1 +...+ a_n a'_n$ and $a_j +J= a^"_1 a^*_1 +... + a^"_m a^*_m$ . Now $I \cap J=\{0\}$ implies that $a_i +a_j= a'_1 a_1 +...+ a_n a'_n + a^"_1 a^*_1 +...+ a^"_m a^*_m$ . But $a_i +a_j$ is arbitrary as $a_i$ and $a_j$ are both arbitrary.

So, $A$ is of finite type generated by $\{ a_1,...,a_n ,a^*_1,..., a^*_m\}$.

Kindly let me know how much of it is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: We cannot tell you how many marks a proof should be worth, that's entirely your instructor's opinion.

Comment: @walkar OK I am editing it to just tell me whether it is right or wrong!

Comment: I am not convinced by your proof. First, since $A$, $A/I$, and $A/J$ are rings, it would likely be easier to use the ideal definition of Noetherian (all ideals are finitely generated). Further, your proof has a variety of formatting issues which make it rather hard to ascertain what argument you are making. Finally, trying to show $A$ is a finitely generated $A$-module will not show that $A$ is Noetherian -- it is always finitely generated by $1$, even if $A$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: @walkar Do you mind writing a complete answer?

Comment: I suggest looking at the answer to this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114707/intersection-of-ideals-is-zero-and-quotients-are-noetherian

Answer (score 1):

There is a canonical exact sequence for any pair of ideals $I,J\le A$:

$$
0 \to I\cap J \to A\to A/I\times A/J \xrightarrow{\varphi} A/(I+J)\to0
$$

The only non-trivial map here is $\varphi$ which is given by

$$
\varphi\colon A/I\times A/J\to A/(I+J),\,(x+I,y+J)\mapsto x-y+(I+J)\,.
$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4115927/537079) for more detail.

This immediately gives the result. Indeed, if $I\cap J=0$, then the above reduces to a short exaxct sequence

$$
0 \to A \to A/I\times A/J \to A/(I+J) \to 0
$$

and there is a general theorem that for a short exact sequence of $A$-modules

$$
0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0
$$

we have that $M$ is Noetherian iff $M'$ and $M''$ are Noetherian. Now recall that $A$ is Noetherian as $A$-module iff $A$ is Noetherian as ring given that submodule are precisely ideals.

The crucial observation here is that if $I\cap J=0$, then $A$ embeds into $A/I\times A/J$ along the usual projections. You do not really need the above exact sequence but it is a neat result anyway.

And your attempt precisely tries to do this, though it is written a bit confusingly. However, you should start with an arbitrary *submodule* and show that it is finitely generated, not with the whole ring. As *walkar* pointed out whole ring (aka the unit ideal) is always finitely generated, even in non-Noetherian rings.

What you then do is to fix a submodule, that is, an ideal $K\le A$ and consider the ideals it generates $K/I\le A/I$ and $K/J\le A/J$. These are now finitely generated by assumption and you can essentially redo your proof for them. To be more precise: you showed exactly this but only of the trivial case of $K=A$.

Comment: "The crucial observation here is if $I\cap J =0$ , then $A$ embeds into $A/I \cross A/J$". Can you please elaborate on it? I am not able to see it.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi Sure. For this we have to compute the kernel of the canonical map $A\to A/I\times A/J$ given by coordiantewise projection, i.e. $a\mapsto(a+I,a+J)$. What does it mean for the image of $a$ be zero? Well, this is, by definition of the quotient ring, the case precisely if $a+I=I$ and $a+J=J$ which translates to $a\in I$ and $a\in J$. But this nothing else than to say that $a\in I\cap J$. Moreover, any $a\in I\cap J$ is mapped to $0$, hence the kernel of this homomorphism is $I\cap J$. Since we assume that $I\cap J=0$ we get that $A\to A/I\times A/J$ is an injection as claimed.