# Free $A$-module and $I$ is a principal ideal generated by a non zero divisor

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

This question was asked in my assignment of commutative algebra and I was not able to solve this question. So, I am looking for help here.

> Question: Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal in a ring $A$. Suppose that $I$ is a free $A$-module. Show that $I$ is a principal ideal, generated by a non-zero divisor.

Attempt: $I$ is a free $A$-module $\implies$ there exists a basis elements $\{i_1, \dotsc, i_r\}$ such that any $i \in I$ can be written as $i = a_1 i_1 + \dotsb + a_r i_r$ and the representation is unique.

To prove: $I$ is a principal ideal $\implies$ there exists an element $i_x$ which generates $I$. Let on the contrary $r \geq 2$ in a basis.

But unfortunately, I don't know which result I should use to find a contradiction and I am not able to move foreward.

Kindly help.

Comment: In the proof, commutativity of $A$ is needed. The result fails for noncommutative rings, such as the ring of polynomials $K\langle x,y \rangle$ in two non-commuting variables $x$ and $y$ over a field $K$, where the left (or right) ideal generated by $x$ and $y$ is a free module of rank $2$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I forgot to mention that the ring is commutative. You are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motivated by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-2-11, we make the following observation.

**Claim.**
The rank of $I$ is at most $1$.

*Proof.*
Otherwise, the ideal $I$ would admit an $A$-basis that contains at least two distinct elements $x_1$ and $x_2$.
This entails that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent, and therefore in parcticular non-zero.
(Here we use that the ring $A$ is non-zero since it contains the non-zero ideal $I$.)
For $a_1 ≔ x_2$ and $a_2 ≔ -x_1$ we would then have the non-trivial linear combination
$$
  a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = 0 \,,
$$
contradicting the linear independence of $x_1$ and $x_2$.
(For this equality, we have used the commutativity of $A$.)
∎

We also know that the rank of $I$ cannot be zero because $I$ is non-zero.
Therefore, $I$ is free of rank $1$.
This means that there exists an element $x$ of $I$ for which the map
$$
  A \to I \,,
  \quad
  a \mapsto ax
$$
is bijective.
The surjectivity of this map tells us that $A$ is a principal ideal with generator $x$, and the injectivity of the map tells us that $x$ is not a zero-divisor.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I am waiting for a solution of this question and I have also put a bounty on it:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585626/solution-verification-of-this-question-related-to-noetheranity . I shall be grateful if you can help me with this solution verification. Thanks!